# perl catalyst relationship has_many

Tags: mysql, perl, catalyst, dbix-class

working code is

```
sub category :Local {
    my ( $self, $c, $path ) = @_;

    my @cat_obj = $c->model('SQL::LasercalibrationCategory')->search({ category_id => $path } );
       my @nav; my $loop = 0; foreach my $r (@cat_obj) {$nav[$loop] = $r->id; $loop++;}
    my $result = $c->model("SQL::Lasercalibration")->search({ id => {-in => [@nav]}  }, { rows => 10 });

     my $page = $c->request->param('page') || 1;
     $page = 1 if ($page !~ /^\d+$/);
     my $rresult = $result->page($page);
     return $c->forward('default') if $rresult == 0;
     $c->stash->{items} = [ $rresult->all ];
     $c->stash->{page} = $page;
     $c->stash->{pager} = $rresult->pager;
     $c->stash->{template} = 'index.tt';
}
```

Here is database st on mysql, table is  lasercalibration and lasercalibration_category.

lasercalibration_category contains all id from table lasercalibration and row category_id wich is contains category relation.

for example on Catalyst when click on http://lasercalibration/category/2 
it collect first in array `@cat_obj` catagory relation. for example category/2 relation is `id 9735 18388 18946 19203 etc.` and then parse all that ids from my `$result = $c->model("SQL::Lasercalibration")->search({ id => {-in => [@nav]}  }, { rows => 10 });`

How may i make it through has_many or has_many_to_many dbxi relationship?
Schema:

Lasercalibration.pm

```
package lasercalibration::Schema::Lasercalibration;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'DBIx::Class';

__PACKAGE__->load_components("Core");
__PACKAGE__->table("lasercalibration");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "id",
  { data_type => "INT", default_value => undef, is_nullable => 0, size => 10 },
  "price",
  { data_type => "FLOAT", default_value => undef, is_nullable => 0, size => 32 },
  "title",
  {
    data_type => "VARCHAR",
    default_value => undef,
    is_nullable => 0,
    size => 255,
  },
  "description",
  {
    data_type => "TEXT",
    default_value => undef,
    is_nullable => 0,
    size => 65535,
  },
  "autoinc",
  { data_type => "INT", default_value => undef, is_nullable => 0, size => 11 },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("id");


# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.04006 @ 2015-02-10 05:55:18
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:uyxHW0E8P7HwFd4a0Zf0lw


# You can replace this text with custom content, and it will be preserved on regeneration
1;
```

LasercalibrationCategory.pm

```
package lasercalibration::Schema::LasercalibrationCategory;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'DBIx::Class';

__PACKAGE__->load_components("Core");
__PACKAGE__->table("lasercalibration_category");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "id",
  { data_type => "INT", default_value => undef, is_nullable => 0, size => 10 },
  "category_id",
  { data_type => "INT", default_value => undef, is_nullable => 0, size => 11 },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("id");


# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.04006 @ 2015-02-10 05:55:18
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:QFvxaRhTcV7FX13vV4lq7w


# You can replace this text with custom content, and it will be preserved on regeneration
1;
```

Comment: I don't see that you have any relationships defined in your result classes. Please describe what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Archive to make join one table to another by category_id.

Comment: OK i'v done with head ache.

Comment: first we need to add __PACKAGE__->has_many(
      "Lasercalibration", "lasercalibration::Schema::LasercalibrationCategory",
      { "foreign.id" => "self.id" },
#      { "foreign.author_id" => "self.id" },
    );
to Lasercalibration.pm

Comment: and __PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
      "lasercalibration::Schema::Lasercalibration",
      { id => "id" },
      { join_type => "LEFT"},
    );
to LasercalibrationCategory.pm

Comment: and     my $result = $c->model('SQL::Lasercalibration')->search({ category_id => $path },{ join => 'Lasercalibration', rows => 10 } );

Comment: Thanks for all for attantion!